# Amazon S3 link expiration during download?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, progress

Does anyone know what happens if an Amazon S3 link expires during the download process? I'm using S3 to offer downloads of a 1.6gig file but I want to set the shortest expiration time possible, somewhere in the neighbourhood of 15 minutes.

If the download is initiated within the 15 minute period, but the download itself takes 1 or 2 hours will that be an issue? I'm assuming once the download is initiated everything is fine right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any downloads initiated before the expiry time will continue to work.

Just be aware that you may run into problems with some file downloaders that attempt to download multiple segments at once. The downloader may not be able to begin new segments after the expiry time and the user may not be able to pause/resume downloads.

Comment: Thanks! A pointer to some authoritative documentation would be great.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-check-expiration